# Macro giving out error "Run-time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

```
Sub Load()

    '
    ' Load Evaluation Macro
    '
    '
    Dim zelda As Integer

    zelda = Lookup()

    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("A" & zelda).Select (highlighted row in yellow)
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("C" & zelda & " :G" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("J" & zelda & " :U" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("C10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("V" & zelda & " :X" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("C26").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("X" & zelda & " :Y" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("C33").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True      

'--------------------Load Comments------------------------------------------

       Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("AA" & zelda & " :AL" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("E9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("AM" & zelda & " :AO" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("E19").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("RawData").Select
    Range("AP" & zelda & " :AQ" & zelda).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    Range("E24").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Range("E1").Select

End Sub

Function LookUp() As Integer

Dim NameAgent As String
Dim EvalID As Integer
Dim nrow As Long
Dim ncol As Long
Dim i As Long

' Look Up Values ---------------------

    Sheets("Evaluation Form").Select
    NameAgent = Range("D1").Value
    EvalID = Range("D6").Value

'------------------------------------
Sheets("RawData").Select
nrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To nrow
     If NameAgent = Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        If Cells(i, 4).Value = EvalID Then

        LookUp = i

        End If
    Else
End If
Next i

End Function
```

I have used this same macro in numerous workbooks and specifically this one is not running correctly. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We don't know what `LookUp` does in `zelda = LookUp()`, nor what line throws the error.

Comment: Plus, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Its points will make your code so much better.

Comment: Sorry, on the second line of the code is where it's highlighted to be the error code.

Comment: `zelda` is probably `0`. I'm assuming your lookup failed.